# How can you change a particular letter to a number?

Tags: python

**How can you change a particular letter to a number?**

programming Language -> Python

```
# english instgram follower version
word1 = "1.9M"
word2 = "20.4K"
word3 = "5.3K"
```

How do you replace 'K' with an integer in a string value stored in a variable?

- K = 1000

Comment: I would get the last character, have a dict with the sizes `{"K": 1000,... }` and then multiply

Comment: ... So what specific result are you expecting? `"1.9M"` becomes `"1900000"`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There is literally a string method called ``replace``. What exactly are you struggling with doing this?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What I wanted was to multiply the unit according to the 'K' or 'M' in the string and appear as an integer.
The result value of ID : Nk03 below was the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex -

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(\\d{0,}.\\d{0,})(M|K)")
testString = "1.23M"
matchArray = regex.findall(testString)
map_dict = {'k': 1000, 'K': 1000, 'm': 1000000, 'M': 1000000}
result = float(matchArray[0][0]) * map_dict[matchArray[0][1]]
```

Comment: That's the answer 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'd like to this question,
I want to study about regular meals, can you tell me the website?

Comment: Do you mean regex?  I use this - https://www.debuggex.com

Comment: how to use site?